How to keep a number of records based on values of another variable in SAS
I have the following data

I need to subset and only keep the number of records based on Total.
Thus: for ABC, only two rows will be kept (since Total=2), and keep the records whose Count=1 and 2 (no matter missing or not). So the count=3 will not be selected.
For LMN, only 3 records will be kept (since Total=3), and keep the records whose Count=1 and 2 and 3 (no matter missing or not). So the count=4 will not be selected.
The output should be like:

I tried to use array, if then, do loops. But really a mess, I have no functional code.
Here are the data contents:
ID     Total  Count   Time
ABC     2        1       .
ABC     2        2     00:00   
ABC     2        3       .
LMN     3      1      02:25   
LMN     3      4       .
LMN     3      3      04:45
LMN     3      2      07:45

Please help, Thank you!

Please post data as text, not photographs.

Sure, will do that in the future posts, thank you for the tip!

First let's convert your listing into an actual dataset.
data have;
  input ID $ Total Count Time :time. @@;
  format time tod5.;
cards;
ABC 2 1 . ABC 2 2 00:00 ABC 2 3 . LMN 3 1 02:25
LMN 3 4 . LMN 3 3 04:45 LMN 3 2 07:45
;

You just need to count how many observations you have seen for each BY group.  You could retain a counter variable.  But an easier way is it nest the SET statement inside a DO loop that will keep count.  If you use the automatic variable _N_ as the counter then you don't need to drop the variable.
data want;
  do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if _n_ <= total then output;
  end;
run;

Result
Obs    ID     Total    Count     Time

 1     ABC      2        1          .
 2     ABC      2        2      00:00
 3     LMN      3        1      02:25
 4     LMN      3        4          .
 5     LMN      3        3      04:45


Thank you so much for the tip! Helped me to open my mind!  For 'LMN' I actually don't need count=4. since total=3, so I only need count=1 or 2 or 3. I think should first sort by count, then follow your codes, or this should also work:
data want ;
set have;
where count <= total ;
run ;

If you want to use the value of your COUNT variable instead of actually counting then the where statement should work.  But that is a different question than what you asked for.

Presume total is distinct within each BY group.  If so, total can be used in a where statement with no need to evaluate any logic involving id.
data want ;
  set have;
  where count <= total ;
run ;  

